# Crash on iOS 9 only: [MKPlacemark initWithCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, unrecognized-selector, mkplacemark

Code:

```
-(void)getRouteDirections{
    MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
    [request setSource:[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation]];

    // It crashes on this line:      
    MKPlacemark * placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:_location.coordinate];
}
```

Exception:

> -[MKPlacemark initWithCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

It crashes only on iOS 9. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `- (instancetype)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkplacemark/2172460-initwithcoordinate?language=objc) is available since iOS10. My guess is that your iPad and your iPhone4S iOS versions are lower...

Comment: @Larme thank you! 
you are right!

but its strange, i remember it worked fine in IOS 8.. anyway, do you know any "MKDirections" code replacements for IOS9?

Comment: `initWithCoordinate:addressDictionary:` is available since iOS3. Was it this one you used before?

Comment: Any luck with a solution for this? I'm experiencing this on iOS 9. Works fine in 10.

Answer (score 3):

Answer from [Larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme) comments:

[`- (instancetype)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkplacemark/2172460-initwithcoordinate) is available since iOS10.

For iOS 9 or earlier, [`initWithCoordinate:addressDictionary:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkplacemark/1451895-initwithcoordinate) is available since iOS 3.